# "Serious Sam" achievement (Serious Sam Bogus Detour)

Tags: achievements, serious-sams-bogus-detour

I'm trying to get the achievement for actually beating the game (The "Serious Sam" achievement), but I'm not sure about the actual requirements. Do I have to beat the game completely unmodified (game switches, not mods), or do I have to beat every level in a save file? I played on a save file onto the last level, but I screwed up and ran out of time, and had to restart the level. I quit the game for a while, and when I came back my save file had corrupted. I was not willing to restart the entire game, so I restarted the final level. I beat it, but I got no achievement. My problem is that I'm not sure if this is because I had game switches turned on, or if It's because I hadn't beaten every level on that save file I actually beat the game on. I've been looking all over the wiki, and I can't find the actual info I need.